# Partition of a regular polygon

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Find   the   values  of  $n$   such   that   there   exist   a   regular   polygon   with  $n$ vertices   such  that   can   be   partitioned   with   isosceles  triangles    with   the   vertices     in  the   vertices of  the  polygon.  The   diagonals  can't   be   intersected.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I misunderstand your question. Does it means 5 is a solution?

[image]

Comment: I think $n=2^{k+1}$ and $n=2^k+1$ are solutions, but not sure about the remaining cases.

Comment: $n=6$ also works: append another triangle on the bottom of your pentagon, and deform to regularity.

Comment: @mr_e_man You are right. To accommodate such kind of solutions, $n=2^k+1$ in my first comment can be modified to $n=2^{p-1}(2^q+1)$.

Comment: That's not clear to me; you could expand your answer to explain why those $n$ work. I can see $n=2^k$ by cutting off the $2^{k-1}$ outermost triangles, leaving a $2^{k-1}$-gon inside, and repeating until it reduces to a square (then cutting the square's diagonal).